# Why no manuscripts of Talmud survive in the Arab lands?

Tags: history, talmud-bavli, talmud-yerushalmi, manuscripts

http://halakhah.com/talmud/nezikin_h.html:

> ...Munich manuscript which covers the whole Talmud and dates from the year 1334. Alas, that that is the only complete manuscript of the Talmud in existence...

It is widely believed that Jews were tolerated much better in the Arab lands than in Europe.

How come no manuscripts of Talmud survived there?

Comment: [Cairo Geniza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cairo_Geniza).

Comment: Who said no manuscripts survived? The Munich manuscript is the oldest complete manuscript. There are certainly older incomplete manuscripts. Indeed it's amazing that any complete manuscripts from that period survived at all intact. I'm not seeing a pattern that indicates that more manuscripts survived in Europe over Africa than expected

Comment: There have been a bunch of recently recovered documents from Afghanistan, being referred to as the "Afghanistan Geniza".  Also, in the secret police of Iraq's headquarter's basement in Baghdad American military personnel discovered a trove of Jewish precious things - Torah scrolls, etc.  According to this article -  http://www.jpost.com/Opinion/Op-Ed-Contributors/Raiders-of-the-lost-archive-329540 -they were allowed to be taken to America for conservation, for eventual return to Iraq--which may or may not happen, since they were looted by Saddam's police from the Jewish community there.

Comment: Neato!  Looking further online for info about the Iraqi documents, I found the site - https://www.ija.archives.gov/ -where the US National Archives are posting all the items from Iraq that they've preserved so far.  The basement where they were found was flooded, so they had to freeze them for the trip to the United States, not an easy thing to do during the war.